# Postgresql Joining tables without losing records

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Let's say I have the following tables:

1 - **StartingStock**:

```
vendor | starting_stock
------------------------
adidas |    13
Reebok |    5
```

2 - **Restock**:

```
vendor | restocks
-----------------
adidas |    2
nike   |    3
```

3 - **Sales**:

```
vendor | quantity_sold
----------------------
adidas |    10
nike   |    1
```

I want my resulting table to be the sell through grouped by vendor. In this scenario, sell through is calculated like this: `quantity_sold/(starting_stock + restocks)`. My only problem is that starting stock and restock tables may not have the some vendors that are present in the sales table. So in the scenario above, `StartingStock` does not have `nike` as a record. So if that's the case the sell though for nike would be just `1/3` or `1/(3+0)`. Therefore, my resulting table would be:

```
vendor | sell_through
---------------------
adidas |    1.5
nike   |   0.33
Reebok |    0
```

So I'd want all of the vendors present in the result table (if it has no sales, value is 0 like Reebok shown above).

I tried working with the different types of joins but I couldn't get it. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a table that contains all vendors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try a full outer join approach here:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(ss.vendor, r.vendor, s.vendor) AS vendor,
    COALESCE(s.quantity_sold, 0) /
        (COALESCE(ss.starting_stock, 0) + COALESCE(r.restocks, 0)) AS sell_through
FROM StartingStock ss
FULL OUTER JOIN Restock r ON ss.vendor = r.vendor
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales s ON s.vendor = COALESCE(ss.vendor, r.vendor)
```

### Demo

Note that I am coming up with 2/3 for the sell through for Adidas, since the quantity sold is 10, and the sum of stocks is 15.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select vendor,
       sum(starting_stock), sum(restock), sum(quantity_sold),
       (sum(quantity_sold) * 1.0 / sum(starting_stock) + sum(restock)) as sell_through
from ((select vendor, starting_stock, 0 as restock, 0 as quantity_sold
       from startingstock
      ) union all
      (select vendor, 0 as starting_stock, restock, 0 as quantity_sold
       from restock
      ) union all
      (select vendor, 0 as starting_stock, 0 as restock, quantity_sold
       from sales
      ) 
     ) v
group by vendor;
```

In particular, this version includes each number in the calculation only once.  A `JOIN` approach will produce inaccurate results if a vendor has multiple rows in any of the tables.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. A vendor will only have one record per table. But I appreciate the answer and will compare it's speed against the other answer when I work with a larger data set.

Comment: @tee . . . With names like "restocking" and "sales", I find that surprising.

Comment: I simplified the question but the sales and restocking tables are a result of other queries where I `group by vendor`